# International Characters are getting corrupted in Mule

Tags: mule, teradata, type-conversion, mule-component, multibyte

I am querying Teradata using Mule Database Connector. I have the value in the table as

`Åland Islands`.

But through debugging I found that the data that is extracted is getting corrupted as

`�land Islands`

My query was simple like

`SELECT CAST(COL1 AS VARCHAR(2000)) AS FIELD_NAME FROM TABLE)`

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Do I need to change the datatype?

Comment: I don't know Mule, but the `�` is a sign that you are receiving non-UTF-8 data through a UTF-8 connection. You may have to make sure that the connection encoding is identical with the table encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pekka 웃 for your suggestion which lead me to debug the issue properly. It was the issue in connection URL where I explicitly added the parameter `CHARSET=UTF16` and thats how the encoding matched and I am getting `Åland Islands` properly in my output. Thanks Again!